# Wordpress footer throwing query error on custom post type archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a relatively simple Wordpress site with two custom post types. In order to successfully paginate the archive pages for these custom post types, I used a query to pre_get_posts with a limit of 5 per page as follows:

```
function post_type_post_queries( $query ) {
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){
    if( is_post_type_archive() ){
  $query->set('posts_per_page', 5);
} } }
```

On all pages there is a footer that features two custom menus placed in the standard widget areas. One links to four pages, of which two of them are the custom post type archives. The other menu features links to the archive of 8 taxonomy terms that are associated with one of the custom post types.

On all pages but the custom post type archives, the footer appears as normal. On the custom post type archive pages, the following error is logged:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_queried_object() on a non-object in wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line 395

which indicates the following function that adds class properties for menu items

```
function _wp_menu_item_classes_by_context( &$menu_items ) {
global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;

$queried_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$queried_object_id = (int) $wp_query->queried_object_id;
```

My assumption is that my queries are colliding somehow, but I'm not sure. Can anyone help me display the footer successfully while also ensuring that the archive pages remain paginated properly?